# How do we check a message that caused a SessionLockLostException error in the service bus?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am getting a few sessionlostlock exceptions while sending some messages to our SB triggered function app. We've set up alerts to check whenever such an error occurs. Although these messages do get retried and there no messages are sent to the DLQ. How do I find out which messages gave these exceptions in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How do I find out which messages gave these exceptions in the first place?

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.sessionlocklostexception?view=azure-dotnet#properties):

- You can use [`MessagingException.Detail Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingexception.detail?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-servicebus-messaging-messagingexception-detail) to get the detail information on the messaging exception.

```
public Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingExceptionDetail Detail { get; }
```

References: [Cause and resolution of SessionLockLostException](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions.md#sessionlocklostexception), [Class SessionLockLostException](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus/1.1.1/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/primitives/SessionLockLostException.html) and [SessionLockLostException(String, Exception)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.sessionlocklostexception.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet)